# How to update a column by adding 1000 for each records in a table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a column name in a table named 'Test' which contains almost 100k rows, I want to update existing values of 'Test' column by adding 1000. For example if a record contains existing value 5555 , it should get updated with 5555+1000 = 6555. In same way, how can i update for all rows in a table?

Answer (score 1):

```
update "Test" set "Test"="Test"+1000
```